# How to overcome indentation error in loops python code

Tags: python, indentation

```
n=int(input("enter any number="))
if n>1:
      for i in range(2,n):
           if(n%i==0):
                print("not prime")
                break
      else:
             print("prime")
             break
else:
    print("not prime")
```

Comment: your else should line up with your if.

Comment: You don't have an `IndentationError`, you just have a random `break` that you don't need (and that is syntactically invalid).

Comment: line 7
    else:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
My code is giving this error

Comment: This is a mixed tabs and spaces issue that isn't readily visible with 4-space tab display settings. Don't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: aha, my IDE fixed it for me automatically when I saved the file to try it out.  :D

Answer (score 1):

Although your indentation is unfortunate (in that it makes your code hard to read, and most IDEs/linters will complain about it), it's not really the source of the error as far as whether or not the program runs correctly.  If you run the exact code that you pasted into your question, you'll see the error:

```
SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop
```

This is because you have a `break` *after* the body of your `for` loop.  Just remove it and the code will work.  With the indentation aligned in a sane way, it should look like this:

```
n = int(input("enter any number="))
if n > 1:
    for i in range(2, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            print("not prime")
            break
    else:
        print("prime")
else:
    print("not prime")
```

The `else: print("prime")` block is part of the `for` statement, *not* the `if` statement inside the loop body of the `for`.  The `else` block of a `for ... else` executes only if the loop runs to completion without a `break` -- in this case, you want to print `prime` only if you don't find *any* number (across the entire `for` loop) that proves it's *not* prime and `break`s the loop.

Comment: line 7
    else:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
My code is giving this error

Comment: Did you get that error before or after you copied and pasted the fixed code above?